# Convert a String | Null to Nullable Number

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using Typescript I am looking for a short approach to covert `string | null` to a nullable number.

I tried to convert the string to number and if it not value then convert it to `undefined` ([Online Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbgS2PaBvAUNaA5vAC4ByAriCAGpgjnwAUAlNAFzQTGKoB2B0AD7RelENjz5oiEuUS8RYgNySAvpKLFY3PgVr0mrDlx78hiqhKnTZ86ACIATAAZ7K-OtXQcOUJBgAQgD2QQDWVtDAQQAm8AD8HKIAtgBGSCrqOCAknEhoGBwIKOiYALwi8ADucHklLCpZOSkhoQCMHMFh0OVYkTHwHADUAIQQtRgAdJrapnp0DCzQcXHQ5LyxAGZ88NHQqg1RvBBB2RMgQQSMzWGtzA3ZxNDXoY4dLd3YfbFDo%20PwUyQKFR9AtWMtVut4FteDs9gcgkcTv9zpdno47kA)).

```
class Service {
  getNullValue() : string | null {
    return null;
  }
  getStringValue() : string | null {
    return "20";
  }
} 

class Book {
  code?: number;
}

let service: Service = new Service();

let book1: Book = { code: +!service.getStringValue() ?? undefined };

console.log(book1);

let book2: Book = { code: +!service.getNullValue() ?? undefined };

console.log(book2);
```

On the console I get:

```
{ "code": 0 }
 
{ "code": 1 }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "and if it not value" what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `+!service.getNullValue() ?? undefined`, you're actually performing four steps.

1. Call `service.getNullValue()`.
2. Logically negate (`!`) the result of (1).
3. Use the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator (`+`) to convert the result of (2) into a number.
4. Coalesce (`??`) the result of (3) and `undefined`.

The order is important. Also important is that TypeScript compiles to JavaScript which has the concept of [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). The behavior you are seeing is a direct result of the truthiness of the return values of your service's methods.

---

In the case of `getNullValue()`, the evaulation is:

1. `service.getNullValue()` returns `null`.
2. `!null` uses the fact that `null` is falsey to return `true`.
3. `+true` converts `true` to `1`.
4. `1 ?? undefined` returns `1`.

Similarly, for `getStringValue()`:

1. `service.getStringValue()` returns `"20"`.
2. `!"20"` uses the fact that a non empty string is truthy to return `false`.
3. `+false` converts `false` to `0`.
4. `0 ?? undefined` returns `0`.

---

I cannot think of a good way to inline the check for `null` and the conversion to a number in the same coalesce statement.

For JavaScript, you can use the fact that [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) returns `NaN` for `null` (among other values) to check whether the result of calling `service.getNullValue()`/`service.getStringValue()` was null.

```js
function getStringValue() { return "20"; }
function getNullValue() { return null; }

var value = parseInt(getStringValue());
console.log(isNaN(value) ? undefined : value);

value = parseInt(getNullValue());
console.log(isNaN(value) ? undefined : value);
```

Since TypeScript checks the type of the parameter for `parseInt(:string)`, I think your best bet is just moving to an explicit null check.

```
let value = this.service.getStringValue();
console.log(value
    ? parseInt(value as string)
    : undefined);

value = this.service.getNullValue();
console.log(value
    ? parseInt(value as string)
    : undefined);
```

Comment: Would `parseInt(service.getNullValue() ?? '')` would be possible? At least it is compiling ...

Comment: When I simply use `parseInt(getNullValue());` as you suggested I get the error `argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: Good catch, I missed that TS would type check even if the function was native JS. I've added another proposed solution to my answer. I'd avoid coalescing the parameter to `parseInt` since you'll still have to convert `NaN` to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like that

```
(Number(YourNullableString) || null)
```

Comment: (Number('0') || null) yeilds null, not 0